# How to configure Makefile to support build for all/multiple artifact types

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

What is the general best practice for creating a Makefile to support building for a specific type of artifact **as well** as support for building all artifact types in one command.

For example, let's say there is a Makefile which supports building of a app on a specific OS:

```
make app OS="Windows"
make app OS="Linux"
make app OS="Mac"
```

Let us say that the Makefile looks something like:

```
my-other-dependency:
    ...
    # Performs commands specific to $(OS)

my-dependency: my-other-dependency
    ...
    # Performs commands specific to $(OS)

app: my-dependency
    ...
    # Performs commands specific to $(OS)
```

To build all artifacts, one can invoke these 3 commands sequentially:

```
make app OS="Windows"
make app OS="Linux"
make app OS="Mac"
```

What is a recommended structure of the Makefile to support an all in one command such as:

```
make app            # build all artifact types (Windows, Linux, Mac)
or
make app OS="all"   # build all artifact types (Windows, Linux, Mac)
```

Or is there something wrong with the pattern above? I am open to any suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use make recursion.  Create a new target like `all-os` or something:

```
.PHONY: all-os
all-os:
        $(MAKE) app OS=Windows
        $(MAKE) app OS=Linux
        $(MAKE) app OS=Mac
```

*ETA* This is another option, that uses a separate target named for each OS to allow parallel builds:

```
OSLIST := Windows Linux Mac

_ostargets := $(addprefix app-,$(OSLIST))
$(_ostargets): app-%:
        $(MAKE) app OS=$*

app-all: $(_ostargets)

.PHONY: app-all $(_ostargets)
```

You can also now run `make app-Windows` instead of `make app OS=Windows`, if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks this is a good suggestion. Would these commands run sequential or in parallel?

Comment: Sequentially: the individual lines of a recipe are never run in parallel.  If you want to run them in parallel you'll need a separate target for each one.  If you use a target named for each OS, rather than setting a variable, you can reuse the same infrastructure.  I'll update my answer.